# Cyrillic Encoding in Urllib Python with lower cases

Tags: python, url, urllib, urlencode

My goal is to encode this dict with `cyrilic` text:

```
target_dict = {"Animal": "Cat", "city": "Москва"}
```

To this (`cyrilic lettesrs with lower case` encoded):

```
Animal=Cat&city=%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0
```

By default with python it encodes with `UPPER CASE`, this is my code:

```
import urllib.parse

target_dict = {"Animal": "Cat", "city": "Москва"}
encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(target_dict)
print(encoded)
```

It returns `city` with `UPPER CASE`, i need only city in lower case:

```
Animal=Cat&city=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0
```

`I need to get city (cyriclic text)` with `lower case`, these two results are actually the same, but service that I am trying to connect wants exactly `lowercase`.

Comment: `encoded.lower()`…!?

Comment: @deceze i cant use .lower() because it will lower all my result, but i need only `one field which containts cyrilic in it`, i've added more data in example, i need `Animal=Cat` stay in its state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses same library, but different method:

```
from urllib import parse


def url_encoded_cyrillic(target_dict):
    url_quote = set()
    result = parse.urlencode(target_dict)
    for value in target_dict.values():
       for char in value:
           encoded_char = parse.quote(char, safe='')
           if encoded_char != char:
               url_quote.add(encoded_char)
    for encoded_item in url_quote:
       result = result.replace(encoded_item, encoded_item.lower())
    return result


target_dict = {"Animal": "Cat", "city": "Москва :/- Москва", "car": "", "tOwn": "New York"}
print(url_encoded_cyrillic(target_dict))
```

it will return:

```
Animal=Cat&city=%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0+%3a%2f-+%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0&car=&tOwn=New+York
```